# Add SSL to heroku with SSL Endpoint

Tags: ssl, heroku

I am trying to add SSL cert to heroku.
When I try to add a certificate

`heroku certs:add server.crt server.key --type endpoint`

I am getting following error.

**Resolving trust chain... done**

**Adding SSL certificate to ⬢ myapp... !**

**Only one SSL endpoint is allowed per app (try certs:update instead).**

And when I try to update certificate as below

`heroku certs:update server.crt server.key --type endpoint`

I am getting following error

**myapp has no SSL certificates**

And when I check for SSL certificates

`heroku certs`

Here's the output

**myapp has no SSL certificates.**
**Use heroku certs:add CRT KEY to add one.**

I am unable to add SSL certificate to heroku.

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add certificates directly from setting sub menu.

1. Add domain
2. Click on configure SSL
3. Add priva6 key and crt
4. If using pointdns update target values